# How to transform this XML from feed with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this partial XML from a feed:

```
<feed>
<entry etag=""W/"datetime'2016-04-01T14%3A13%3A46.4027343Z'""">
</entry>
</feed>
```

And I can't transform it with XSLT into another XML doc. I get the following error:

```
Error reported by XML parser: Element type "entry" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

Even with just this: (XSLT 2.0)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is you can't, because the partial XML is not well-formed, and XSLT only works with well-formed XML. The issue is the XML parser will (probably) parse the `etag` attribute as `etag=""` (i.e. an empty attribute) and what follows that is just some random string, which causes the parse error. The correct solution would be go back to whatever is generating this "XML" and get it to generate something valid. Thanks!

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. Try this instead: <feed> <entry etag="'W/'datetime'2016-04-01T14%3A13%3A46.4027343Z'"> </entry> </feed>

Comment: Note that if you want to have quotation marks inside an attribute value, the correct way to do it would be to "escape" the relevant symbols: `<entry etag="W/&quot;datetime'2016-04-01T14%3A13%3A46.4027343Z'&quot;">`